# Why does an 'access is denied' message appear when I log in to an Ubuntu share folder?

Tags: permissions, samba

1. I created 2 machines: Windows 10, Ubuntu 18.04.
2. I installed Webmin 1.881 then, installed Samba Windows File Sharing (by Webmin) in Ubuntu
3. I created a folder to be shared in Ubuntu.
4. I went to **WEBMIN > System > Users & Groups** and created a user with password and include it in the Sambashare group.
5. I converted the user to a Samba user by WEBMIN
6. I went to **WEBMIN > Servers > SAMBA Windows File Sharing** and created a new file share of the folder I had created (I set create with group = Sambashare).
7. I ran the command: `sudo pdbedit -L`, and the user was listed
8. I ran the command: `testparm -s`. The output was:

   ```
   Load smb config files from /etc/samba/smb.conf
   rlimit_max: increasing rlimit_max (1024) to minimum Windows limit (16384)
   WARNING: The "syslog" option is deprecated
   Processing section "[printers]"
   Processing section "[print$]"
   Processing section "[test222]"
   Loaded services file OK.
   Server role: ROLE_STANDALONE

   # Global parameters
   [global]
           dns proxy = No
           log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
           map to guest = Bad User
           max log size = 1000
           obey pam restrictions = Yes
           pam password change = Yes
           panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
           passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
           passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
           server role = standalone server
           server string = %h server (Samba, Ubuntu)
           syslog = 0
           unix password sync = Yes
           usershare allow guests = Yes
           idmap config * : backend = tdb


   [printers]
           browseable = No
           comment = All Printers
           create mask = 0700
           path = /var/spool/samba
           printable = Yes


   [print$]
           comment = Printer Drivers
           path = /var/lib/samba/printers


   [test222]
           path = home/hiddai/linshare
   ```
9. I restarted the SAMBA service.
10. I went to WIN 10 > run and typed: `\\UBUNTU_IP\{ShareFolderName}`
11. I typed in username:

    ```
    '{username}' , password: ******
    'UBUNTU1804\\{username}' , password: ******
    ```

    As a result I got a message 'Access is denied' and I ask WHY?

Comment: Add to your original question the output of the following command - without quotes: "testparm -s"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The credentials weren't including the password.

I found that when I checked the converted user in **WEBMIN > SAMBA Windows File sharing > Samba users**. The user's password wasn't set.

Logging in with username only solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
[test222]
        path = home/hiddai/linshare'
```

- That is a read only share so if you try to add something to it Win10 will issue a **Destination Folder Access Denied** error.
- Although it is not a problem for samba and it will work just fine as it is from a Linux perspective your path is missing a leading `/` as in `/home/hiddai/linshare`
- I don't know if that apostrophe at the end of **linshare'** is a typo or if that is the real name of the folder. If it's a typo Win10 will issue a **Windows cannot access \\server\test222** error.
- And one other complication may be if hiddai's home directory is encrypted. If it is then only one user will be able to access that share and that is hiddai.

If your intent was to create a writeable share that requires authentication to access on a folder in an encrypted home folder you might want to see if something like this works better:

```
[test222]
        path = /home/hiddai/linshare
        read only = No
        force user = hiddai
```